# R shiny brush zoom in plot ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, heatmap

[image]I developed an interactive correlation heat map at: https://lingjun.shinyapps.io/code/

The problem is that when I take a brush on the left plot to zoom in and get the right plot, there is always excessive labels for x and y axes on the left bottom corner in the right plot. I want the labels to cut off sharply.

The code in the server class is:

```
observe({
    brush <- input$zoom_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
        ranges$x <- c(round(brush$xmin), round(brush$xmax))
        ranges$y <- c(round(brush$ymin), round(brush$ymax))
    } else {
        ranges$x <- NULL
        ranges$y <- NULL
    }
})
output$zoomplot <- renderPlot({


        x.index <- y.index <- 1:300

        zoomplot <- ggplot(melt(result[x.index, y.index]), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + xlab("Q1") + ylab("Q2")+ scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",  high = "red",limits=c(-1, 1), guide=FALSE)+coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = (ranges$y),expand=F)



        zoomplot

    },  height = 500, width = 500)
```

Here is the ui code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("SCIP survey response correlation heatmap"),
  selectInput("Correlation", 
          label = "Choose which to display",
          choices = list("corPSR", "Spearman", "difference"),
          selected = "corPSR"),

  fluidRow(
column( width=5,

  h4("Click and drag to zoom in"),
  plotOutput("heatmap", 
             #click = "plot1_click",
             brush = brushOpts( id = "zoom_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)),
  h4("Points near click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click_info")),

column(width=7,

  h4("Click to see details"),
  plotOutput("zoomplot", click="plot1_click"))
```

))

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: And maybe the `ui` lines responsible for showing the `zoomplot` and the base plot.

Comment: I have editted the post to include the screenshot and ui code. As you can see from the screenshot, the zoomplot has extra labels clustered at the left bottom corner, although I specify the range to be the region included by the brush.

Comment: I posted the wrong code to begin with :). It is correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky. It is arguably a bug in `coord_cartesian`, but only happens with factor coordinates.

One way to get this to work would be to do without that and just filter the melted dataframe. Note that you are filtering on the integer value of the factor coordinate.

Here is some code that does that gets what you need.

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)

n1 <- 90000
n2 <- 90000
nr <- 300
nc <- 300
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n1), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
y <- matrix(rnorm(n2), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
result <- cor(x,y)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h2("baseplot"),plotOutput("baseplot",width="100%", height="600px",brush="zoom_brush"),
    h2("zoomplot"),plotOutput("zoomplot",width="100%", height="600px")
  )
)

## server.R
server <- function(input, output) {

  ranges <- reactiveValues(x=NULL,y=NULL)
  observe({
    brush <- input$zoom_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(round(brush$xmin), round(brush$xmax))
      ranges$y <- c(round(brush$ymin), round(brush$ymax))
    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })
  meltDf <- reactive({
    x.index <- y.index <- 1:300
    mdf <- melt(result[x.index, y.index])
    mdf$Var1 <- as.factor(mdf$Var1)
    mdf$Var2 <- as.factor(mdf$Var2)
    mdf
  })
  output$baseplot <- renderPlot({

    mdf <- meltDf()

    ggplot(mdf, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
      geom_tile() + xlab("Q1") + ylab("Q2")+ 
      scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",  high = "red",limits=c(-1, 1), guide=FALSE)
  },  height = 500, width = 500)

  output$zoomplot <- renderPlot({

    if (is.null(ranges$x)) return(NULL)

    mdf <- meltDf()
    print(ranges$x)
    print(ranges$y)
    mdf <- mdf[ ranges$x[1]<=as.integer(mdf$Var1) & as.integer(mdf$Var1)<= ranges$x[2],]
    mdf <- mdf[ ranges$y[1]<=as.integer(mdf$Var2) & as.integer(mdf$Var2)<= ranges$y[2],]
    ggplot(mdf, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
            geom_tile() + xlab("Q1") + ylab("Q2")+ 
            scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",high = "red",limits=c(-1, 1), guide=FALSE)
  },  height = 500, width = 500)
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

it then looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I definitely tried the same workaround. But the problem is that once I used the manually filtered data frame instead of the "range" method, the "points near click" lose track of the original data frame and does not display the correct click information any more.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that problem, with my example? Yours is not an MCVE...

Comment: Basically, I want to show the details of the point I clicked on the zoom plot. But if I used filtered method, the details information is not corresponding to the correct information as supposed.

Comment: You can check the original shiny app link. On the left bottom panel, there are details information(TS, LB, UB). If I use the filtered data frame, the information shown there is not the points I clicked at.

Comment: Yeah, I could probably fix this, but I have put a lot of work into your tasks already, and all things considered there are greener fields. Maybe someone else will want to take a look. Good luck..

Comment: i made an upvote and i would expect you to do so as well @Sheldon. You dont have to accept the answer, but it was good effort on a tricky question. Telling people what they did is not correct and stating that you tried that already (but not mention that in the question!!) is not good practise, sry. Whenever I come in that situation I feel like time was wasted, because the question was not well asked. It sounds harsh, I am aware, just an info on how you can improve the info you give to people who take time to answer your challenges :)

Comment: @BigDataScientist I apologize for any confusion. But I state clearly that I want to get rid of the extra labels instead of a workaround. If it is indeed a bug in ggplot, it's worth to report to the authors I guess.

Comment: thats what i actually when i first saw the question unanswered. For me it is about to show what you attempted yourself (which is really good that you did so!), so it doesnt have to be redone when its not useful,... just a hint (we can also discuss in chat, if its unclear..). Have a nice week!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an old bug that has been rectified in ggplot2 but resurfaces in this type of Shiny plot somehow?

You can use scales in addition to coord_cartesian as long as you don't set limits again. It's still tricky to work out how to set the breaks and labels, and will depend on whether your variables are factors or characters.

You'll need scale_x_discrete() and scale_y_discrete() and, in the case of a character variable, something like this:

`p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = sort(plot_data$Var1)[round(min(ranges$x)):round(max(ranges$x))],
labels = sort(plot_data$Var1)[round(min(ranges$x)):round(max(ranges$x))])`

Sorting the variable before indexing should imitate the plotting behaviour of ggplot.